# libcurl crashes on iOS 9 when compiled with latest iOS sdk

Tags: ios, c, curl, libcurl, ios10

In iOS 10 there is `clock_gettime` function in system library.

When i compile curl on latest iOS SDK, `configure` script always define `HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME_MONOTONIC` (but i define `-miphoneos-version-min=8.0`!), that lead to crash on previous iOS versions. Crash looks like `EXC_BREAKPOINT (EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT)` on `dylib stub_binder`. Crash occurred when `curlx_tvnow()` is called. With `HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME_MONOTONIC` it calls `clock_gettime`, that is not exists on pre-iOS 10.

Is there any way to disable `HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME_MONOTONIC` when `-miphoneos-version-min` less then 10.0?

Comment: For now i just remove some lines from `configure` to disable `HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME_MONOTONIC` test.

Comment: yeah, xcode8 / macos 10.12 broke things ... the curl configure script needs to be adjusted for that but hasn't yet been fixed. See https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2016-09/0043.html for more details

Comment: `-Werror=partial-availability` in `CFLAGS` seems like better solution then manually edit `configure` (from https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2016-09/0051.html)

Comment: For POCO users: https://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=6878&p=12801#p12801

Answer (score 0):

i have compile the CURL(https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) with adding **CFLAGS= CFLAGS + "-miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -Werror=partial-availability"** and its working fine for me.